# Where is this dinosaur from?

Tags: tv, character-identification

I was looking through some T-Shirts from shows from my early childhood, and I came across this one:

[image: Dinosaur with armour and weapon]

Where is this dinosaur from? What show? I feel like I know it...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is the *Tyrannosaurus Rex* from the [1988 cartoon series/extended toy ad *Dino-Riders*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dino-Riders)

[image]

[image]

[image]

The quote, obviously, is from *Jurassic Park*.

Comment: There is also a beautiful (and hence especially ridiculous) painting of a Dino Riders battle on the very bottom of [this page](http://collider.com/dino-riders-movie-adaptation/) (right-click the image and open it in a new tab or window to see an enlarged version, perhaps suitable for a desktop background).

Comment: "Extended toy ad"...

Comment: I didn't know how badly I needed this in my life.